# Unable to make ethping program because of missing pcap definitions

Tags: c, linux, gcc, pcap, libpcap

I seem to be having an issue building the ethping executable.  It cannot find any of the functions that are defined in `pcap.h`.

At first I thought it wasn't finding `pcap.h`, but I have checked the `$PATH` and `/usr/include` is there (the `pcap.h` there is a stub that then includes `pcap/pcap.h`, but that looks all good too).

I even tried `-I /usr/include` and `-I /usr/include/pcap`, but still no luck.

I have searched through tons of forum postings, but could not find a solution.  So that's why I am here.  Any ideas?

```
root:src# gcc -Wall -Werror -ggdb -g -O2 -lpcap -o ethping ethping.o ieee8021ag.o dot1ag_eth.o 
ethping.o: In function `timeout_handler':
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:65: undefined reference to `pcap_breakloop'
ethping.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:183: undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:202: undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:203: undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:254: undefined reference to `pcap_next_ex'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:257: undefined reference to `pcap_perror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Similarly:

```
root:src# gcc -Wall -Werror -ggdb -g -O2 -lpcap -I /usr/include/pcap -o ethping ethping.o ieee8021ag.o dot1ag_eth.o 
ethping.o: In function `timeout_handler':
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:65: undefined reference to `pcap_breakloop'
ethping.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:183: undefined reference to `pcap_open_live'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:202: undefined reference to `pcap_compile'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:203: undefined reference to `pcap_setfilter'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:254: undefined reference to `pcap_next_ex'
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/dot1ag-utils-master/src/ethping.c:257: undefined reference to `pcap_perror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
root:src#
```

Comment: The reason you haven't had any luck fiddling with the `-I` arguments are because these errors are *linker* errors, not header-file errors.  The compiler is finding your header files just fine.  The problem is with the library being linked with the `-lpcap` argument.  You need to be investigating `libpcap.so` instead.

Comment: gcc handles parameters in the order they are given,  so after all compiler options, after all object files, then the library path, then the library name.  This is probably the root of your problem.

Comment: thanks for posting this here. i'm pondering if i should try to integrate it in a custom distro, and i would certainly have run into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the compile line fixed it.  Placing `-lpcap` at the far right got it going as suggested.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -ggdb -g -O2  -o ethping ethping.o ieee8021ag.o dot1ag_eth.o -lpcap
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are  invoking the linker *without* the arguments to include the libpcap library, or the libraries are not installed.  See http://www.tcpdump.org/ to obtain the library.  Or if you are on a well-supported distribution, use the applicable install command:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

or

```
sudo yum install libpcap-dev
```